# Zuul proxy same request to another port

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I want to be able to proxy with Zuul running on a Spring Boot server listening to port X to port Y where an nginx is listening on the same machine. I want to send the same URL, parameters, etc.

The reason I am doing this is that using a `ZuulFilter` which is doing some checks.

For example I want to get to `localhost:8943/humans/get/1` and send the request to `localhost:8080/humans/get/1`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you can do that. What are you expecting from an answer? You have provided no code for us to look at.

Comment: I consider it a pretty generic question, so some article/tutorial/code example would be considered an answer :)

Comment: You can configure static routes to localhost:port in your zuul application.yml. I've done this for local testing.

Comment: Ok, I can configure it to listen to a port and send it to another port to which I have to provide the exact URL, but how do I send the same request to a different port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do it with the following configuration:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    services:
      path: /**  
      url: http://localhost:8043/
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
zuul:
  routes:
    humans:
      path: /humans/**
      url: http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: I almost agree with this answer, I've managed to do exactly what I wanted. See my answer.